# How to upload file in Drupal 7 with forms?

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-7

I have troubles with Drupal 7 and file uploading.

My code that doesn't work:

```
function test_form($form, &$form_state){

$form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
$form['podcast'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Audio file',
    '#type' => 'file',
);
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
);
return $form;

}

function test_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

$vals = $form_state['values'];
$filepath = 'public://test/';
//$filepath = 'temporary://test/';
$filename = 'rcc_date.mp3';

file_prepare_directory($filepath, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
$file = file_save_upload('podcast', array('file_validate_extensions' => array()), $filepath.$filename);
//got FALSE here. Why?
die(print_r($file===FALSE).'-');

}
```

So path created but file doesn't uploads and file_save_upload returns FALSE. Also I tried array() and true as $validators with no effect.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How to get the filename dynamically ?

Comment: The filename is completely unnecessary in this code.  Leave it out completely.  Don't set the $filename variable, and don't append it to $filepath.

Comment: To use an empty array of file validators, like array('file_validate_extensions' => array()), is unsafe and shouldn't be used.  Use NULL instead, to take the default, or make a real list yourself.  See the note in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh. $destination shouldn't contain filename, just path.

Comment: For those of you wondering where $destination is, it's the third argument to file_save_upload.  That line should look like this:  $file = file_save_upload('podcast', array('file_validate_extensions' => array()), $filepath);  Or preferably, like this: $file = file_save_upload('podcast', null, $filepath); This is a lot more secure.  It doesn't allow PHP files, for example, to be uploaded, which would be a huge security risk.  See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7